# Node JS : Date.now() taking server start time instead of current time in mongoos

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
notification_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  },
```

I have tried with new Date() also but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works correctly

```
notification_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andolsi Jihed

Comment: Not at all, if you need anything node js mongodb ... I'm here

Answer (score 1):

`default: Date.now()` associates current date which is equals time when you server is started, you should consider using `default: Date.now` instead. In this case instead of specific value resolver function will be provided

```
notification_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
```